# How do I convert avi and mkv to Mp4 while preserving quality using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

How do I convert avi and mkv to Mp4 using ffmpeg?  I would like to preserve the quality of the video during conversion as best as possible.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  You're talking about different compressions.  You're going to get some quality loss no matter how you try.

Comment: Hi, how to convert with less loss quality ?

Comment: I've edited your question to better match what you're asking for.  I don't know how to use ffmpeg but I'm someone around here does.

Comment: The comment by KronoS is totally incorrect. This is a container conversation.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the the source material is using codecs that the mp4 container supports, then what you are looking for is a simple transmux. in ffmpeg you can accomplish this like:

```
ffmpeg -i {your in file} -acodec copy -vcodec copy {your out file}
```

This tells ffmpeg not to decode and re-encode the elementary streams, but simply copy them from one container to another.